# Resize only the first image inside a post with CSS without affecting any other image

Tags: wordpress, css

How can I resize only the first image present inside a post with CSS without affecting any other image inside the post. If I use the following code:

```
#content div.single:nth-of-type(n) img {
width: 448px !important;
height: 252px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin-top: 0;
```

It resizes all the images present inside the post.

I have also tried nth-child with no success:

```
#content div.single img:nth-child(1){
width: 448px !important;
height: 252px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin-top: 0;}
```

Here is [the Demo](http://bit.ly/1fHlhm3)

Comment: `:first-child` pseudo selector should work...btw you only have 1 image per post on that page so all the images inside your posts on that page will be affected - if you are indeed targeting the 1st image inside each post... did you by any chance mean the first image inside the FIRST post on the page?

Comment: Do you want to change the GTA logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it easily with CSS like this:

```
.single p:nth-child(2) > img {
width: 448px !important;
height: 252px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not target the image you want like this:

```
.alignnone.size-full.wp-image-35095 {
width: 448px !important;
height: 252px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

when you have a class with spaces you target the class in css but you change every space with a dot.

If you want always to target the first image in a post then you can run Jquery:

```
$( "#content img" ).first().attr('width', '150');
```

Btw you have an important in your first image and I was struggling why this is not working :P

Comment: He wants it per post. If you do that, it's just for one specific post and that's wrong.

Comment: Do you approve it now?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
#content div.single img:first-child {
 width: 448px !important;
 height: 252px !important;      
 padding: 0 !important;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```